# Android app crashes upon replacing fragment:

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I followed the tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions) on how to make Fragment Transactions but whenever I hit my button to transact the fragment my app crashes. My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    public Fragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
    public Fragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, loginFragment).commit();

        } else {

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, mainFragment).commit();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    public void login() {

        transaction.replace(R.id.container, mainFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    public static class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

        public LoginFragment() {

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class MainFragment extends Fragment {

        public MainFragment() {

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.pointlight.kingdomcraft.MainActivity$LoginFragment" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_submit"
        android:onClick="login" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So in conclusion The submit button on the login fragment replaces the login fragment with the main fragment, or so it should but instead it crashes.

To narrow it down, in the xml I set the button to `android:onCLick= "login"` which in turn calls the login method inside my activity class:

```
public void login() {

            transaction.replace(R.id.container, mainFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
```

What have I done wrong, I've been working on fragments transactions for two days to no justice.

Logcat:

?:??: W/?(?): --------- beginning of /dev/log/main

?:??: W/?(?): --------- beginning of /dev/log/system

EDIT:

If I debug and hit the submit button instead of crashing the button gets highlighted blue and the app freezes

Comment: Thats the thing I look in the logcat and its empty except for the two lines on startup

Comment: read my edit this is wierd

Comment: Post correct logcat because this says nothing

Comment: Thats ignorant to say after I just said my logcat only displays 2 lines

Comment: but if i look under the debug view it says exception IllegalStateException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature for your `onClick` handler `android:onClick="login"` is wrong:

```
public void login() {
```

should be

```
public void login(View v) {
```

`android:onClick` attribute gets translated to code that looks up the handler by method name using reflection. The lookup process also requires method signature i.e. parameter types. If the signature doesn't match, the method cannot be found and an exception is thrown.

Comment: also why is my logcat vurtualy empty that is wierd

Comment: if the view v isn't even used why is it required?